# Find Unique Characters in a File

Tags: search, parsing, scripting

I have a file with 450,000+ rows of entries. Each entry is about 7 characters in length. What I want to know is the unique characters of this file.

For instance, if my file were the following;

> ```
> Entry
> -----
> Yabba
> Dabba
> Doo
> ```

Then the result would be

> Unique characters: {abdoy}

Notice I don't care about case and don't need to order the results. Something tells me this is very easy for the Linux folks to solve.

### Update

I'm looking for a very fast solution. I really don't want to have to create code to loop over each entry, loop through each character...and so on. I'm looking for a nice script solution.

### Update 2

By **Fast**, I mean fast to implement...not necessarily fast to run.

Comment: You will have to loop one war or another and you won't know how fast it is until you tried. "Less Text" is not necessarily "faster".

Comment: How can you "parse" it w/o looking at every byte? That's just impossible.

Comment: I'm looking for the impossible :) It seems Bash, or PowerShell can do the trick.

Comment: You could probably do some evil tricks with sed, sort, uniq and/or wc, but they'll definitely not be faster than a custom script.

Comment: How could you know which characters are unique without looking at all characters?

Comment: What does "fast" means to you? A) Something that you can easily copy/paste and don't make you think? Or B) Something that runs fast?

Comment: Note that "fast to implement" goes out the window once you post your question on how to do it online and start waiting for people to give you advice. You would've been quicker done if you've just done a really bad solution yourself.

Comment: @lassevk. You're right. I did do a solution in C# just now. I really don't like how clunky it feels. So now I am enjoying learning new ways to do things so in the future I can implement the solution faster.

Comment: @lassevk: I can't agree. Look at the speed at which answers have appeared here. This might actually be faster than programming an own soluton by trial & error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a **PowerShell** example:

```
gc file.txt | select -Skip 2 | % { $_.ToCharArray() } | sort -CaseSensitive -Unique
```

which produces:

> D
>    Y
>    a
>    b
>    o

I like that it's easy to read.

**EDIT**: Here's a faster version:

```
$letters = @{} ; gc file.txt | select -Skip 2 | % { $_.ToCharArray() } | % { $letters[$_] = $true } ; $letters.Keys
```

Comment: As much as I like PowerShell, it is not a good solution for this many rows. The script has been running for at least 5 min using 1.7 GB of memory.

Comment: Bummer.  I wonder if PowerShell v2 will do any better?  I bet replacing the `sort` with an accumulation set (like some of the other answers) would improve the memory performance.  I will ponder it.

Comment: There, I wrote one that uses a hashtable as a set.

Answer (score 20):

BASH shell script version (no sed/awk):

```
while read -n 1 char; do echo "$char"; done < entry.txt | tr [A-Z] [a-z] |  sort -u
```

**UPDATE**: Just for the heck of it, since I was bored and still thinking about this problem, here's a C++ version using set. If run time is important this would be my recommended option, since the C++ version takes slightly more than half a second to process a file with 450,000+ entries.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main() {
    std::set<char> seen_chars;
    std::set<char>::const_iterator iter;
    char ch;

    /* ignore whitespace and case */
    while ( std::cin.get(ch) ) {
        if (! isspace(ch) ) {
            seen_chars.insert(tolower(ch));
        }
    }

    for( iter = seen_chars.begin(); iter != seen_chars.end(); ++iter ) {
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I'm ignoring whitespace and it's case insensitive as requested.

For a 450,000+ entry file (chars.txt), here's a sample run time:

```
[user@host]$ g++ -o unique_chars unique_chars.cpp 
[user@host]$ time ./unique_chars < chars.txt
a
b
d
o
y

real    0m0.638s
user    0m0.612s
sys     0m0.017s
```

Comment: To me sed/awk are part of a shell: If the shell is available and sed/awk are not, then I'm in bizzaro-world ;-)

Comment: But thats some nice work there ... always good to learn some new tricks.

Comment: But: "sort -u" should be a lot more efficient than "sort | uniq"

Comment: @saua - Noted, I removed the call to uniq after I checked the manpage to sort. Old habit ;)

Comment: I'm afraid the while-lop at the beginning really slows things down, as this is still by far the slowest bash-alternative in this thread, it seems.

Comment: @saua - yes, not exactly speedy as requested, but then if speed is the major concern I'd probably want to write this in C anyway.

Answer (score 12):

As requested, a pure shell-script "solution":

```
sed -e "s/./\0\n/g" inputfile | sort -u
```

It's not nice, it's not fast and the output is not exactly as specified, but it should work ... mostly.

For even more ridiculousness, I present the version that dumps the output on one line:

```
sed -e "s/./\0\n/g" inputfile | sort -u | while read c; do echo -n "$c" ; done
```

Comment: You're missing a `wc -l` at the end. Other than that, nice solution. I tried something similar but didn't get it to work (I forgot the `g` option on sed).

Comment: "wc -l"? As I understand he's not interested in the number of unique characters but in which ones there are. Did I get that wrong?

Comment: @Konrad: but I stole your sed-magic using "\0" it looks much nicer that way. Thanks ;-)

Comment: You're welcome. I'll probably delete my other answer in due course since it's now redundant.

Comment: This doesn't ignore case, if you pipe the sed output through "tr [A-Z] [a-z]" before passing to sort, it'll ignore case also, and it's only a few tenths of a second slower.

Comment: the while at the end could be replaced by tr -d "\n"

Answer (score 6):

Use a `set` data structure. Most programming languages / standard libraries come with one flavour or another. If they don't, use a hash table (or generally, dictionary) implementation and just omit the value field. Use your characters as keys. These data structures generally filter out duplicate entries (hence the name `set`, from its mathematical usage: sets don't have a particular order and only unique values).

Comment: But my solution works, the array doesn't (of course I'm using Unicode files). ;-)

Comment: I also claim that the array solution *is* in fact an optimized and specialized set.

Answer (score 6):

Quick and dirty C program that's blazingly fast:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int chars[256] = {0}, c;
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    chars[c] = 1;
  for(c = 32; c < 127; c++)  // printable chars only
  {
    if(chars[c])
      putchar(c);
  }

  putchar('\n');

  return 0;
}
```

Compile it, then do

```
cat file | ./a.out
```

To get a list of the unique printable characters in `file`.

Comment: Nice, very fast, however it doesn't handle accented characters (anything non-ASCII). Try this test case:
cat /usr/share/dict/american-english | ./a.out

Comment: I assumed that Brig only cared about ASCII.  If not, that's easy to fix - just change the 127 in the loop bound to 256.

Comment: I agree, nice and fast! Doesn't ignore the case of the characters as requested, but easy enough to fix with a call to tolower() in the while loop.

Answer (score 5):

Python w/sets (quick and dirty)

```
s = open("data.txt", "r").read()
print "Unique Characters: {%s}" % ''.join(set(s))
```

Python w/sets (with nicer output)

```
import re

text = open("data.txt", "r").read().lower()
unique = re.sub('\W, '', ''.join(set(text))) # Ignore non-alphanumeric

print "Unique Characters: {%s}" % unique
```

Answer (score 2):

A very fast solution would be to make a small C program that reads its standard input, does the aggregation and spits out the result.

Why the arbitrary limitation that you need a "script" that does it?

What exactly is a script anyway?

Would Python do?

If so, then this is one solution:

```
import sys;

s = set([]);
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline();
    if not line:
        break;
    line = line.rstrip();
    for c in line.lower():
        s.add(c);

print("".join(sorted(s)));
```

Comment: Using a set is slightly faster than using a list and checking for contains every time, as @Jough did.

Comment: Not only “slightly” actually. For large files, the difference is truly significant, i.e. in the order of O(n^2) vs. O(n).

Comment: You're confusing n's here. the n in question for this algorithm is the number of unique characters, not the size of the file, so it's not that big a performance hit. That said, if you only care about ASCII characters then a bitfield is the easiest approach.

Comment: There's ways to make this superfast by using assembly code piped to an assembler, thus keeping in line with the "script" part of the question, but my solution is quick to implement and runs decently fast. Yes, it can be improved, but is it necessary?

Answer (score 2):

Algorithm: 
    [Slurp](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2003/11/21/slurp.html) the file into memory.

```
Create an array of unsigned ints, initialized to zero.

Iterate though the in memory file, using each byte as a subscript into the array.
    increment that array element.

Discard the in memory file

Iterate the array of unsigned int
       if the count is not zero,
           display the character, and its corresponding count.
```

Comment: This only works if you assume a 8 bit encoding and therefore don't support unicode characters. Or at least you'll need to modify the bitfield size.

Comment: He is talking characters, not unicode.  He also could have probably implemented and adequate solution by now, without help.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat yourfile | 
 perl -e 'while(<>){chomp;$k{$_}++ for split(//, lc $_)}print keys %k,"\n";'
```

Answer (score 1):

<del>Alternative solution using bash:</del>

```
sed "s/./\l\0\n/g" inputfile | sort -u | grep -vc ^$
```

**EDIT** Sorry, I actually misread the question. The above code *counts* the unique characters. Just omitting the `c` switch at the end obviously does the trick but then, this solution has no real advantage to saua's (especially since he now uses the same `sed` pattern instead of explicit captures).

Answer (score 1):

While not an script this java program will do the work. It's easy to understand an fast ( to run )

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class  Unique {
    public static void main( String [] args ) throws IOException { 
        int c = 0;
        Set s = new TreeSet();
        while( ( c = System.in.read() ) > 0 ) {
            s.add( Character.toLowerCase((char)c));
        }
        System.out.println( "Unique characters:" + s );
    }
}
```

You'll invoke it like this:

```
type yourFile | java Unique
```

or

```
cat yourFile | java Unique
```

For instance, the unique characters in the HTML of this question  are:

```
Unique characters:[ , , ,  , !, ", #, $, %, &, ', (, ), +, ,, -, ., /, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, :, ;, <, =, >, ?, @, [, \, ], ^, _, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z, {, |, }]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Print unique characters (ASCII and Unicode UTF-8)

```py
import codecs
file = codecs.open('my_file_name', encoding='utf-8')

# Runtime: O(1)
letters = set()

# Runtime: O(n^2)
for line in file:
  for character in line:
    letters.add(character)

# Runtime: O(n)
letter_str = ''.join(letters)

print(letter_str)
```

Save as *unique.py*, and run as `python unique.py`.

Answer (score 0):

in c++ i would first loop through the letters in the alphabet then run a strchr() on each with the file as a string. this will tell you if that letter exists, then just add it to the list.

Comment: Which alphabet?  What if the alphabet you use is significantly smaller than the file?  What if it's considerably larger?

Comment: well he already gave his filesize in the question. im not sure of the performance differences in each, i imagine it would depend on how much memory you have.

Comment: Or what if the file is very large but only contains a few characters from the alphabet? This will scan through the whole input file multiple times.

Comment: point take, then maybe after finding the character you remove all instances of it from the search string.  this way it speeds up as it finds more.

Answer (score 0):

Python without using a set.

```
file = open('location', 'r')

letters = []
for line in file:
    for character in line:
        if character not in letters:
            letters.append(character)

print(letters)
```

Comment: I dunno.. just an alternative.

Comment: Why not just use a dictionary, should be of the same order of magnitude as a set, and is as integrated into the language as lists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this file with [JSDB Javascript](http://www.jsdb.org) (includes the javascript engine in the Firefox browser):

```
var seenAlreadyMap={};
var seenAlreadyArray=[];
while (!system.stdin.eof)
{
  var L = system.stdin.readLine();
  for (var i = L.length; i-- > 0; )
  {
    var c = L[i].toLowerCase();
    if (!(c in seenAlreadyMap))
    {
      seenAlreadyMap[c] = true;
      seenAlreadyArray.push(c);
    }
  }
}
system.stdout.writeln(seenAlreadyArray.sort().join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Python using a dictionary.  I don't know why people are so tied to sets or lists to hold stuff.  Granted a set is probably more efficient than a dictionary.  However both are supposed to take constant time to access items.  And both run circles around a list where for each character you search the list to see if the character is already in the list or not.  Also Lists and Dictionaries are built in Python datatatypes that everyone should be using all the time.  So even if set doesn't come to mind, dictionary should.

```
file = open('location.txt', 'r')
letters = {}
for line in file:
  if line == "":
    break
  for character in line.strip():
    if character not in letters:
      letters[character] = True
file.close()
print "Unique Characters: {" + "".join(letters.keys()) + "}"
```

Answer (score 0):

A C solution.  Admittedly it is not the fastest to code solution in the world.  But since it is already coded and can be cut and pasted, I think it counts as "fast to implement" for the poster :)  I didn't actually see any C solutions so I wanted to post one for the pure sadistic pleasure :)

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define CHARSINSET 256
#define FILENAME "location.txt"

char buf[CHARSINSET + 1];

char *getUniqueCharacters(int *charactersInFile) {
    int x;
    char *bufptr = buf;
    for (x = 0; x< CHARSINSET;x++) {
        if (charactersInFile[x] > 0)
            *bufptr++ = (char)x;
    }
    bufptr = '\0';
    return buf;
}

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char c;
    int *charactersInFile = calloc(sizeof(int), CHARSINSET);
    if (NULL == (fp = fopen(FILENAME, "rt"))) {
        printf ("File not found.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while(1) {
        c = getc(fp);
        if (c == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        if (c != '\n' && c != '\r')
            charactersInFile[c]++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("Unique characters: {%s}\n", getUniqueCharacters(charactersInFile));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where `C:/data.txt` contains 454,863 rows of seven random alphabetic characters, the following code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"C:/data.txt");
            Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.Length);

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            Hashtable table = new Hashtable();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:/data.txt");
            while (!sr.EndOfStream) {
                char c = Char.ToLower((char)sr.Read());
                if (!table.Contains(c)) {
                    table.Add(c, null);
                }
            }
            sr.Close();

            foreach (char c in table.Keys) {
                Console.Write(c);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

produces output

`4093767

mytojevqlgbxsnidhzupkfawr

c

889

Press any key to continue . . .`

The first line of output tells you the number of bytes in `C:/data.txt` (454,863 * (7 + 2) = 4,093,767 bytes). The next two lines of output are the unique characters in `C:/data.txt` (including a newline). The last line of output tells you the number of milliseconds the code took to execute on a 2.80 GHz Pentium 4.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution using grep (assuming the file name is "file"):

```
for char in a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z; do 
    if [ ! -z "`grep -li $char file`" ]; then 
        echo -n $char; 
    fi; 
done; 
echo
```

I could have made it a one-liner but just want to make it easier to read.

(EDIT: forgot the -i switch to grep)

Answer (score 0):

Well my friend, I think this is what you had in mind....At least this is the python version!!!

```
f = open("location.txt", "r") # open file

ll = sorted(list(f.read().lower())) #Read file into memory, split into individual characters, sort list
ll = [val for idx, val in enumerate(ll) if (idx == 0 or val != ll[idx-1])] # eliminate duplicates
f.close()
print "Unique Characters: {%s}" % "".join(ll) #print list of characters, carriage return will throw in a return
```

It does not iterate through each character, it is relatively short as well.  You wouldn't want to open a 500 MB file with it (depending upon your RAM) but for shorter files it is fun :)

I also have to add my final attack!!!!  Admittedly I eliminated two lines by using standard input instead of a file, I also reduced the active code from 3 lines to 2.  Basically if I replaced ll in the print line with the expression from the line above it, I could have had 1 line of active code and one line of imports.....Anyway now we are having fun :)

```
import itertools, sys

# read standard input into memory, split into characters, eliminate duplicates
ll = map(lambda x:x[0], itertools.groupby(sorted(list(sys.stdin.read().lower()))))
print "Unique Characters: {%s}" % "".join(ll) #print list of characters, carriage return will throw in a return
```

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387623/find-unique-characters-in-a-file#387882) above mentioned using a dictionary.

If so, the code presented there can be streamlined a bit, since the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) states:

> It is best to think of a dictionary as
>   an unordered set of key: value pairs,
>   with the requirement that the keys are
>   unique (within one dictionary).... If
>   you store using a key that is already
>   in use, the old value associated with
>   that key is forgotten.

Therefore, this line of the code can be removed, since the dictionary keys will always be unique anyway:

```
    if character not in letters:
```

And that should make it a little faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
s=open("text.txt","r").read()
l= len(s)
unique ={}
for i in range(l):
 if unique.has_key(s[i]):
  unique[s[i]]=unique[s[i]]+1
 else:
  unique[s[i]]=1
print unique
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know, but here's a fast solution, meaning it runs fast, and it's probably also pretty fast to code if you know how to copy/paste ;)

**BACKGROUND**
I had a huge csv file (12 GB, 1.34 million lines, 12.72 billion characters) that I was loading into postgres that was failing because it had some "bad" characters in it, so naturally I was trying to find a character not in that file that I could use as a quote character.

#### 1. First try: Jay's C++ solution

I started with [@jay's C++ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/387720/9638991):

(Note: all of these code examples were compiled with `g++ -O2 uniqchars.cpp -o uniqchars`)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main() {
    std::set<char> seen_chars;
    std::set<char>::const_iterator iter;
    char ch;

    /* ignore whitespace and case */
    while ( std::cin.get(ch) ) {
        if (! isspace(ch) ) {
            seen_chars.insert(tolower(ch));
        }
    }

    for( iter = seen_chars.begin(); iter != seen_chars.end(); ++iter ) {
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Timing for this one:

```
real    10m55.026s
user    10m51.691s
sys     0m3.329s
```

#### 2. Read entire file at once

I figured it'd be more efficient to read in the entire file into memory at once, rather than all those calls to `cin.get()`. This reduced the run time by more than half.

(I also added a filename as a command line argument, and made it print out the characters separated by spaces instead of newlines).

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::set<char> seen_chars;
    std::set<char>::const_iterator iter;
    std::ifstream ifs(argv[1]);

    ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t size = ifs.tellg();
    fprintf(stderr, "Size of file: %lu\n", size);
    std::string str(size, ' ');
    ifs.seekg(0);
    ifs.read(&str[0], size);

    /* ignore whitespace and case */
    for (char& ch : str) {
        if (!isspace(ch)) {
            seen_chars.insert(tolower(ch));
        }
    }

    for(iter = seen_chars.begin(); iter != seen_chars.end(); ++iter) {
        std::cout << *iter << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Timing for this one:

```
real    4m41.910s
user    3m32.014s
sys     0m17.858s
```

#### 3. Remove `isspace()` check and `tolower()`

Besides the set insert, `isspace()` and `tolower()` are the only things happening in the for loop, so I figured I'd remove them. It shaved off another 1.5 minutes.

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::set<char> seen_chars;
    std::set<char>::const_iterator iter;
    std::ifstream ifs(argv[1]);

    ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t size = ifs.tellg();
    fprintf(stderr, "Size of file: %lu\n", size);
    std::string str(size, ' ');
    ifs.seekg(0);
    ifs.read(&str[0], size);

    for (char& ch : str) {
        // removed isspace() and tolower()
        seen_chars.insert(ch);
    }

    for(iter = seen_chars.begin(); iter != seen_chars.end(); ++iter) {
        std::cout << *iter << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Timing for final version:

```
real    3m12.397s
user    2m58.771s
sys     0m13.624s
```

Answer (score 0):

The [simple solution from @Triptych](https://stackoverflow.com/a/387890/5634162) helped me already (my input was a file of 124 MB in size, so this approach to read the entire contents into memory still worked).

However, I had a problem with encoding, python didn't interpret the UTF8 encoded input correctly. So here's a slightly modified version which works for UTF8 encoded files (and also sorts the collected characters in the output):

```
import io
with io.open("my-file.csv",'r',encoding='utf8') as f:
    text = f.read()
    print "Unique Characters: {%s}" % ''.join(sorted(set(text)))
```