# How to enumerate unique characters in a UTF-8 document? With sed?

Tags: utf-8, sed, unique, character

I'm converting some Polish<->English dictionaries from RTF to HTML. The Polish special characters are coming out fine. But IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet) glyphs get changed to funny things, depending on what program I use for conversion.  For example, /ˈbiːrɪ/ comes out as /ÈbiùrI/ or /∪βιρΙ/.

I'd like to correct these documents with a search & replace, but I want to make sure I don't miss any characters and don't want to manually pore over dictionary entries.  I'd like to output a list of all unique, NON-ascii characters in a document.

I found this thread:
[Find Unique Characters in a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387623/find-unique-characters-in-a-file)

... and I tried the following two proposals:
sed -e "s/./\0\n/g" inputfile | sort -u
sed -e "s/(.)/\1\n/g" inputfile | sort -u

They both work nicely, and seem to both generate the same output. My problem is that they only output standard ASCII characters, and what I'm looking for is exactly the opposite.

The sed tool looks awesome, but I don't have time to learn it right now (though I intend to later).  I'm hoping the solution will be clear to someone who's already mastered this tool, and they can save me a lot of time.  [-:

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a `sed` solution but a Python solution. It reads the contents of a file, takes it as UTF-8 and then turns it into a set (thus throwing away duplicates), throws away ASCII characters (0-127), sorts it and then joins it back together again with a blank line between each character:

```
'\n'.join(sorted(set(unicode(open(inputfile).read(), 'utf-8')) - set(chr(i) for i in xrange(128))))
```

As something you'd run from the command line if you felt so inclined,

```
python -c "print '\n'.join(sorted(set(unicode(open('inputfile').read(), 'utf-8')) - set(chr(i) for i in xrange(128))))"
```

(You could also use `''.join` instead of `'\n'.join` which would list the characters without a newline in between.)